# Unbounded Daterangepicker

Tags: datepicker, ngx-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I want to build a form that includes a time range, specifically a period of validity. My tech stack is Angular with Bootstrap, so using something like the [NgxBootstrap daterangepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker) would be nice.

Now the problem is that validity periods may be bounded or unbounded, i.e. in addition to bounded periods like **from 01.01.2019 till 31.01.2019** it should also be possible to define unbounded periods like **from 01.01.2019** (without an end date).

Can this be properly done with a daterangepicker like the one from NgxBootstrap, or should I resort to two separate datepickers (one of them being nullable)?